# Jmeter Debug Sampler Not Showing Regular Expression Extractor variables

Tags: jmeter, header

I'm having some issues getting the variables from a Regular Expression Extractor to show in the View Results Tree.

[Reg Ex and Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Tdx.png)

The Regular Expression Extractor is a child of the HTTP Request. The Debug Sampler and the View Results Tree are at the same level as the HTTP Request. I am trying to extract the Authorization Token.

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkEGA.png)

As you can see, I get a 200 response from the server with the Token.

[View Results Tree with no RegEx variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Dbg.png)

But I'm not even seeing the RegEx variables in the Debug Sampler. I would expect to see them, even if the Extractor didn't pull anything from the response. Am I missing a node? Looking in the wrong place? Using the wrong elements?

I've burned half a day researching and trying different things, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your regular expression is not correct, you should be using something like `(.*)` as your one will not match anything if you don't provide right boundary which you don't have. You can attempt sticking to [line break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_break) character but it might not work if your token comes last
2. You're looking into wrong tab of the View Results Tree listener, [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (including [pre-defined ones](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)) live under `Response Data -> Response Body path`

   [image]

   Check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about JMeter tests troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: Thank you, Dimitri. I got it working with your suggestion.